# Cannot call spsolve

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to convert some code to sparse matrices. I see that I should be able to use spsolve from http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve

However when I try it, I get compiler errors on -

`no matching function call to 'spsolve(arma::spmat&, arma::sp_mat&)`

The error line is -
    `arma::sp_mat xu = arma::spsolve(WuT, YTCupu);`

from [here](https://github.com/sanealytics/recommenderlabrats/commit/75b26446f3c8366aae43c698d8e036482cea6544)

I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Here is what's loaded

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] recommenderlabrats_1.0    RcppArmadillo_0.7.100.3.1 recommenderlab_0.2-0     
[4] registry_0.3              proxy_0.4-16              arules_1.4-1             
[7] Matrix_1.2-6             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1     Rcpp_0.12.6     grid_3.3.1      irlba_2.0.0     lattice_0.20-24
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the [spsolve documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve) again:

> where A is a sparse matrix, B is a dense matrix or vector, and X is unknown

There is no present way in armadillo to solve two sparse matrices the best that can be done is:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void arma_solve_tester() {
    // SPARSE
    arma::sp_mat A = arma::sprandu<arma::sp_mat>(1000, 1000, 0.1);

    arma::vec b = arma::randu<arma::vec>(1000);    // DENSE
    arma::mat B = arma::randu<arma::mat>(1000, 5); // DENSE

    arma::vec x = spsolve(A, b);  // solve one system
    arma::mat X = spsolve(A, B);  // solve several systems
}
```

Glancing over [`Eigen`'s sparse documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html) I'm not entirely sure you will be able to use that either.

Comment: Solving for 'sparse on sparse' would be a nice addition, or possibly even new micropackage (also exporting the call).

Comment: Should be an upstream push to armadillo if it is developed. I will have to look into sparse algorithms.

Comment: Might be a question for Ryan as the sparse stuff tends to come from the MLPACK use. We can email them.

Comment: Thanks, that would really help. I am dealing with large sparse matrices, taking more memory than needed will really be a downer.

Comment: Hi there, I'm just checking on the status of this. My use case is testing recommendation algorithms. So these matrices are really large and sparse.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel did you manage to send the e-mail or should I toss it out to Ryan Curtin?

Comment: Please do. I didn't get to it.

Comment: Hi there, just checking on the status of this. For testing recommendation algorithms, this is a very useful feature as all I have is large sparse matrices. Thanks again.